# Activeadmin disable batch action for single row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

`admin/user.rb`

```
  index row_class: ->user { 'active' if user.deleted_at? } do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :name
    actions
  end

  User.all.each do |user|
    if user.deleted_at?
      config.batch_actions = false
    end
  end
```

At the moment i have batch actions for all the users. However, I don't want batch action select box present for soft deleted users. I tried to loop through all the users and made batch_actions false for deleted_at users. But that doesn't seems to be working. Is it even possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand fully, but do you need to config.save after you make batch_actions false?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the source for `selectable_column` to do it:

```
column resource_selection_toggle_cell, class: 'col-selectable', sortable: false do |resource|
  if resource.can_be_selected?
    resource_selection_cell resource
  end
end
```